# How to exit and close FX Text Editor (the text editor of FX File Explorer)?

Tags: applications

Though I have used FX File Explorer (by NextApp) occasionally for over 10 years, I just used the text editor of this app for the first time. This was to paste a URL into an empty file. ok, this was done, and the file was saved. But I cannot exit, and I cannot close the editor. No key sequence does it.

For many hours, I have googled to find documentation, a reference manual, or any relevant internet article. I found nothing.

Please give me some advice.

Regards

Comment: When asking a question about third party apps please always include a link to the app in Play Store.

Comment: Have you tried the usual system-wide "Back" gesture?